# Can you help me identify baby snails in my freshwater aquarium?

Tags: aquarium, freshwater, snails, identification

I have a freshwater aquarium which I added plants and two nerite snails to approximately two weeks ago.  Today  I noticed two baby snails -- one about 2mm long, the other about 1mm.  As noted I do have two nerites, but expected they wouldn't reproduce in freshwater (and believe they came from freshwater prior to aquiring them--however I'm not 100% certain).

Both appear similar to--their feet are slender and extend behind their shells coming to a point, and their tentacles are long.  I struggled to get a photo using a loupe and a phone, but managed to get a couple pictures.

Here's a closeup showing the foot and antenna (as well as some very small worms at the bottom-left -- hopefully Rhabdocoela).
[image: Closeup of unidentified snail]

And here's a less zoomed photo, with the both snails (the smaller of the two is quite blurry--right at the meniscus of the water above the larger snail).
[image]

Thanks for any guesses!

Comment: You can typically bait them with lettuce or spinach and then remove it with them included. If you crush the ones on the glass with something flat like a butterknife, most any fish in the tank will eat what's leftover of them. They tend to get out of control really fast since they can reproduce both sexually and asexually, so if you can control them before there's a real problem, it will be much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bladder snail,they grow to about 1,5 cm in lenght and can live for up to two years.

They multiply fast but they mainly eat waste products so they are not a threat to your fish and plants,you will over time get way too many of them so you will have to remove them to keep the population down.

source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physella_acuta

If you want to remove bladder snails(and many other types of snails)the best solution is to introduce a few predatory snails into your tank,the best type of snail you can use is Anentome helena https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anentome_helena.

Comment: Thanks!  I did a thorough cleaning today and rounded up five in total.  I'll keep an eye out for more and will get an assassin if they keep appearing.